# Converting Files to PDF and attaching to another PDF in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, pdf-generation

So I'm doing a project that generates a PDF of information that was previously filled out in a form. Along with this information, documents were attached to support the information in the form.

I generate the PDF with the normal info from my DB, but I also want to convert their uploaded files (if .doc or .docx) to  PDF format and stick in the same PDF. (So it is all in one place.)

I know how to convert to PDF, problem is how do you attach those newly generated PDFs to the current one with the other information on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have 2 options:

1. merge all PDFs into one using `<cfpdf action="merge"...>`
2. really attach files in your main pdf but as CFPDF does not support it (yet?) you have to use iText:

   ```
   <cfscript>
       try {
           // Source of THE main PDF and destination file
           inputFile = ExpandPath("myDoc.pdf");
           outputFile = ExpandPath("myDocPlusAttachments.pdf");

           // the file to attach (can be of any type)
           attach1     = ExpandPath("myAttachment.doc");

           // prepare everything
           reader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( inputFile );
           outStream = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init( outputFile );
           stamper = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper").init( reader, outStream );

           // attachment the file
           stamper.addFileAttachment("My Attached File", javacast("null", ""), attach1, "myAttachment.doc");

           // display the attachment pane when the pdf opens (Since 1.6)  
           writer = stamper.getWriter();
           writer.setPdfVersion( writer.VERSION_1_6 );   

       }
       finally {
           // always cleanup objects
           if (IsDefined("stamper")) {
                  stamper.close();
           }
             if (IsDefined("outStream")) {
                 outStream.close();
             }
       }
   </cfscript>
   ```

Just found where I got that piece of code: [ColdFusion 9: Adding Document Level Attachments to a PDF with iText](http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2010/02/coldfusion-9-adding-document-level.html)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [CFPDF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7995.html) tag, and use the `merge` action.